# Parametrising the unit circle without sine and cosine

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Is there a nice way to make a **smooth** and **periodic** parametrisation $\gamma\colon\mathbb R\to S^1$ of the unit circle $S^1$ in $\mathbb R^2$ that does *not* somehow involve sine/cosine or (what I find to be equivalent) the complex exponential function --- and nor functions related to or derived from them. Preferably, if $\tau > 0$ is the period of $\gamma$, the restriction $\gamma\colon[0,\tau)\to S^1$ should be a **bijection**.

Comment: Perhaps I should elaborate more on what I mean by "related to or derived from them". Or rather, I'll state the purpose: I'm writing a note where I argue that Euler's formula should be taken as a *definition* of cos and sin, while their relation to the unit circle should be derived from that. The reason is that angle (a topic that involves arc length) must be defined using a parametrisation of the unit circle; but the most obvious parametrisation involves cos and sin --- or that's what I'm saying at least.

Comment: But when I say that, I'd better be right. So is it true, are there no obvious parametrisations of $S^1$ that do not somehow rely on Euler's formula?

Comment: Offhand it seems to me you could take $\gamma : t \mapsto \left\langle 1-4t, \sqrt{1-(1-4t)^2}\right\rangle$ for $t\in\left[0, \frac12\right)$, then $t\mapsto \left\langle 4t-3, -\sqrt{1-(4t-3)^2}\right\rangle$ for $t\in\left[\frac12, 1\right)$. This is piecewise, but still smooth.

Comment: What about the Weierstrass parameterization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Comment: If "periodic with period $\infty$" is allowed, then $t\mapsto (1-t^2,2t)/(1+t^2)$ does it.  The domain is $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$, and $\infty$ is not $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, but is a single $\infty$ at both ends of the line. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MJD: The circle you describe is smooth, but the way I see it, the function isn't even differentiable at $t=\frac12$, so it cannot be smooth in the strict sense. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Don't the derivatives match up at $t=\frac12$? If not, please pardon my error.  I did not actually do the calculation, which is why I posted only a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: @mvg Oh, of course the derivatives don't match up.  Do you think I should delete the suggestion, or do you think the mistake is instructive enough that I should leave it?

Comment: @MJD: I'd say keep it. After all, even if OP requires real smoothness, other users might find this in a situation with weaker requirements. And your formula is at least shorter than mine, although I'm not too fond of square roots. I don't achieve $C^\infty$ either, only $C^1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll combine three parts.

- Let's start with the fractional part function, and adapt that so it maps $\mathbb R$ to $[-1,1)$: $$f_1:t\mapsto 2(t-\lfloor t\rfloor)-1$$ This ensures a period of $\tau=1$.
- The next part is a rational parametrization of the semicircle, which maps $[-1,1)$ to the right half of a circle with radius $2$ and center $(-1,0)$:
  $$f_2:t\mapsto\frac1{1+t^2}\begin{pmatrix}1-3t^2\\4t\end{pmatrix}$$
- Then comes a stereographic projection to the unit circle:
  $$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\frac1{x^2+y^2+2x+1}\begin{pmatrix}x^2-y^2+2x+1\\2y(x+1)\end{pmatrix}$$

Combine all of this, use $t':=t-\lfloor t\rfloor$ as a shorthand, and you get

$$
\gamma:t\mapsto\frac1
{4t'^4 - 8t'^3 + 8t'^2 - 4t' + 1}
\begin{pmatrix}
4t'^4 - 8t'^3 + 4t' - 1 \\
-8t'^3 + 12t'^2 - 4t'
\end{pmatrix}
$$

For $t'=0$ and $t'=1$ the function values agree on $(-1,0)$, so it is continuous. The first derivatives agree as well on $(0,-4)$ so it is $C^1$ as well. Unfortunately, the second derivative $(16,\pm8)$ is different for both values, therefore the function is not $C^2$ and hence not smooth. At least not in the strict sense of the word. But perhaps $C^1$ is enough for you?

The circle formed by this function is perfectly smooth, and you even get the bijection you asked for. The rational representation in combination with the floor function is certainly far from any trigonometric or complex exponential functions.

I would *guess* that if you require the function to be not only smooth but analytic, then any possible function boils down to $\sin(g(t))$ and $\cos(g(t))$ where $g$ is some analytic function. I don't have a proof for this, only some rough ideas. So in that case the question “are there any fundamentally different parametrizations” would be answered “no”. This still leaves room for non-analytic but smooth functions.